# Port forwarding does not work for http server

Tags: http, port, router, forwarding

I created simple http server (using Delphi idHttpServer).

The problem is: request from internet cannot reach my pc. 
Router is Asus RT-N15U (with TomatoUSB). Windows firewall disabled.

I have real IP, and other services work fine (RDP, VNC, even WOL). 
Also 192.168.1.11:1122 (my internal IP) works fine.

I used different ports, but no result. Ports are open (checking using online tools).
What am I doing wrong?

Settings:
firewall: https://db.tt/jLIP5YF0
port forwarding: https://db.tt/lJvQ2EC7

Comment: Did you check your firewall (both on your computer and modem/router)?

Comment: Yes. Attached settings screenshots

Answer (score 0):

Problem was in router firmware.
Updated to newest version of TomatoUSB firmware.